# How to transform multi array according to first element in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, zip, coding-efficiency

I have an array like this:

```
[[0,21], 
 [1,23], 
 [1,21], 
 [0,23], 
 [1,24]]
```

what is the fastest way to transform it into two array like these:

```
a = [21,23]
b = [21,23,24]
```

I know to do this with looping, is there any library to do this?

Comment: The logic behind the transformation is not clear.

Comment: if array[i][0]==1 it goes to b, if 0 it goes to a

Comment: just edited the wrong placed 21,21 should be 21,23 in a

Comment: `itertools.groupby` is the library that could make this solution elegant

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using numpy:-

```
import numpy
a=[[0,21], 
 [1,23], 
 [1,21], 
 [0,23], 
 [1,24]]

b=numpy.array(a)
c = numpy.array([[False,True],[False,True],[False,True],[False,True],[False,True]])
print(b[c][:2])
print(b[c][2:])
```

Alternatively,we can achieve by numpy.arange().We are creating array c from b by giving index of those element which we want from each of the nested arrays. Here we want second element from each of those nested arrays.So here(1,1,1,1,1) in this case.After getting array c,we did slicing as desired.

```
import numpy
a=[[0,21], 
 [1,23], 
 [1,21], 
 [0,23], 
 [1,24]]

b=numpy.array(a)
c=b[numpy.arange(len(b)),[1,1,1,1,1]]
print(c[:2])
print(c[2:])
```

Comment: do we need to define the filter variable, like [1,1,1,1,1]?

Comment: @kira, yes you need to give index of the element which you want from every nested array. Here in your case,  you want 21,23,21,23,24.  Each having index 1 in those arrays.  So used [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: so we need to count 1 on list

Comment: No need to count. Just provide index of element from each array. We are providing index(according to nested array) of those element which we want from those nested arrays.

Comment: its mean we need to generate index array first